Proof of the sieve of Eratosthenes
I need to write the code for the sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm so that it is verifiable, that is, to verify that the method really returns only prime numbers.
I tried to add invariants and guarantees to the code, but I can't prove anything to the verifier. My idea is this: in Eratosthenes Sieve comes an array of bool values of size n+1, from 0 to n. True is a prime number, False is a composite number. I iterate through the numbers from 2 to the root of n and if the number is prime, then I cross out the numbers to the right in the array that are divisible by this prime number, starting with a doubled prime number. This is an algorithm with optimizations, but I would like to verify at least an algorithm without optimizations. It seems to me that it can be proved this way: the index i goes from left to right from 2 to the root of n. If we encounter sieve[i] == true, then we remove all numbers greater than i and multiples of i from the array. Therefore, if we meet sieve[i] == false, then exists k :: k < i==> j % k == 0, because initially all the elements of the array were equal to true. Otherwise, if we met sieve[i] == true, it means forall k :: k < i ==> i % k != 0, so i is a prime.
But simple assertion might not hold. How to fix that? Or how to proof it simpler?
My code:
predicate is_prime(k: nat)    
{
    k > 1 && forall d :: 2 <= d < k ==> k % d != 0
}


method EratosthenesSieve(n: nat) returns (primes: set<nat>)        
    requires n > 2    
    //[1] i want to proof it:
    ensures forall k :: k in primes ==> is_prime(k)
    //[2] i want to proof it:
    ensures forall k :: 2 <= k <= n && is_prime(k) ==> k in primes
{
    var sieve: array<bool> := new bool[n+1];
    forall i:nat | 2 <= i < n { sieve[i] := true; }    

    var i: nat := 2;
    assert forall i:nat :: 2 <= i < n ==> sieve[i] == true;
    while i * i < n
        invariant 2 <= i < n < sieve.Length        
        decreases n - i
    {
        if sieve[i] {            
            forall j:nat | (i * i <= j < n) && (j % i == 0) { sieve[i] := false; }    
            //[3] assertion might not hold        
            assert forall j:nat :: (i * i <= j < n) && (j % i == 0) ==> sieve[j] == false;
        }
        i := i + 1;
    }
    primes := {}; 
    for i := 2 to n {
        if sieve[i] {
            primes := primes + {i};
        }
    }    
}


I verified a version of this. It does not fit on one slide let's say.  https://github.com/hath995/Dafny4.4/blob/main/examples/Sieve.dfy

An alternate way to specify primes is with factors. It may help to have two definitions which you can show are the equivalent, certain proofs about one can be easier to prove than the other.
  ghost predicate IsFactor(p: nat, x: nat) {
    exists q: nat ::  p * q == x
  }

  ghost function Factors(x: nat): set<pos> {
     set p: nat | p <= x  && IsFactor(p, x)
  }

  ghost predicate Prime(p: nat) {
    Factors(p) == {1, p}
  }


Here are some links that have examples using those definitions.
gcd.dfy
linear combinations
However, to verify your code as is will require writing a good number of lemmas to explain basic number theory facts to Dafny. Secondly, your loop invariants are very underspecified. You will need to define invariants which describe the state of the sieve at any state, including partial results. These must be inductively true, i.e., the work inside the loop body implies those same invariants in the next step. You will likely need a few lemmas to do this.
As an approach first comment out the if statement and inside the loop an prove to Dafny that the loop terminates correctly. Currently, it does not.
